# Reverse position of vowels in a string

Tags: php, replace, reverse, offset

I want to reverse the order of vowels in a string. I have written the below code, but the result set is empty.

Example -

"hello", return "holle"

"leetcode", return "leotcede"

Help me to achieve this.

```
<?php
function reverseVowels($string) {

    $result = '';
    
    $string = array();
    $vowels = array();
    
    $strlength = count($string);
    for ($i=0; $i < $strlength; $i++) {
        $orig = $strlength[$i];
        $char =  strtolower($strlength[$i]);

        if ($char === 'a' || $char === 'e' || $char === 'i' || $char === 'o' || $char === 'u') {
            array_push($vowels, $orig);
            $orig = null; 
        }
        
         array_push($string, $orig);
       
    }
    $new_strlength = count($string);
    
    for ($i=0; $i < $new_strlength; $i++) {
        if (!$string[$i]) {
            $string[$i] = array_splice($vowels, count($vowels) - 1, 1);
        }
    }
    
    $result = $string;
    return $result;
  
}

$res = reverseVowels("hello hello");
print_r($res);

//"hello", return "holle"
//"leetcode", return "leotcede"
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the changed and working code:

```
function reverseVowels($str) {
  $result = '';
    $string = array();
    $vowels = array();
    $strlength = count($str);
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $orig = $str[$i];
        $char =  strtolower($str[$i]);
        if ($char === 'a' || $char === 'e' || $char === 'i' || $char === 'o' || $char === 'u') {
            array_push($vowels, $orig);
            $orig = null; 
        }
         array_push($string, $orig);
    }
    $new_strlength = count($string);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($string); $i++) {
        if (!$string[$i]) {
            $string[$i] = array_splice($vowels, count($vowels) - 1, 1)[0];
        }
    }
    $result = $string;
    return $result;
}
$res = reverseVowels("leetcode");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

I've reworked yours slightly:

```
function reverseVowels($string)
{
    $result = '';
    $out    = [];
    $vowels = [];

    $len = strlen($string);

    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $orig = $string[$i];
        $char = strtolower($string[$i]);
        if (in_array($char, ['a','e','i','o','u'])) {
            $vowels[] = $orig;
            $orig = null; 
        }
        $out[] = $orig;
    }

    for ($i=0, $j=count($vowels)-1; $i < $len; $i++)
        $result .= $out[$i] == null
            ? $vowels[$j--]
            : $out[$i];

    return $result;
}
```

Alternatively with array functions:

```
function reverse_vowels(string $str)
{
    $vowels       = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    $replacements = [];
    $chars        = str_split($str);
    $replacements = array_intersect($chars, $vowels);
    $replacements = array_combine(
        array_keys($replacements),
        array_reverse($replacements)
    );
    $chars  = array_replace($chars, $replacements);

    return implode('', $chars);
}

echo reverse_vowels('stackoverflow');
```

Output:

```
stockevorflaw
```

Answer (score 1):

I love functional style - it produces shortest code. So here it is :

```
function reverse_vowels($word) {
    $vowels = implode(array_filter(str_split($word),
              function ($c) {return preg_match('/[aeiou]/i', $c);}));
    $v = 0;
    $reverse = implode(array_map(
              function ($i) use ($word, $vowels, &$v) {
                 $is_vowel = preg_match('/[aeiou]/i', $word[$i]);
                 return $is_vowel ? $vowels[strlen($vowels) - 1 - $v++] : $word[$i];
              }, range(0, strlen($word) - 1)));
    return $reverse;
}

echo reverse_vowels('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
```

Outputs:

> Tho qaeck brewn fox jumps ovor thi luzy deg

Nice question !

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy method,

```
<?php

$str = "leetcode";
$v = array("a","e","i","o","u");


$replace = array();

for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
    if(in_array($str[$i],$v))
    $replace[$i] = $str[$i];
}

$replaceIndex = array_reverse(array_keys($replace));
$replaceValue = array_values($replace);
$replace = array_combine($replaceIndex,$replaceValue);

foreach($replace as $key=>$value){
  $str[$key] = $replace[$key];
}

echo $str;


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that works fine

```
function solution($str) {
    $vowels = [];
    $strArr = str_split($str);
    foreach ($strArr as $char) {
      if (in_array($char, ['a','e','i','o','u']) && !in_array($char, $vowels)) {
        $vowels[] = $char;
      }
    }
    $result = "";
    foreach ($strArr as $char) {
      $pos = array_search($char, $vowels);
      if ($pos === false) {
        $result .= $char;
        continue;
      }
      if ($pos == 0) {
        $result .= $vowels[1];
        continue;
      }
      if ($pos == 1) {
        $result .= $vowels[0];
        continue;
      }
      if ($pos % 2 == 0 && array_key_exists(($pos+1), $vowels)) {
        $result .= $vowels[$pos+1];
        continue;
      }
      if ($pos % 2 == 0 && !array_key_exists(($pos+1), $vowels)) {
        $result .= $vowels[$pos];
        continue;
      }
      if ($pos % 2 != 0) {
        $result .= $vowels[$pos-1];
        continue;
      }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Extracted from my repository https://github.com/sodmond/vowel_reversal

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are only processing strings of single-byte characters, you can make replacements based on offsets using array syntax.

First, generate an array of vowels and tell `preg_match_all()` to store their original offsets/locations.

Then iterate the matched vowel array and replace the vowel locations from right to left with the vowels from left to right.

If you are unfamiliar with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag, use `var_export($m)` to see the produced multidimensional array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/civeE)) ([Demo with expressive variables](https://3v4l.org/bMVt2))

```
$strings = [
    'hello',
    'leetcode',
    'atwood'
];

foreach ($strings as &$string) {
    $count = preg_match_all('~[aeiou]~', $string, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; ++$i) {
        $string[$m[0][$count - $i][1]] = $m[0][$i - 1][0];
    }
}
var_export($strings);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'holle',
  1 => 'leotcede',
  2 => 'otwoad',
)
```